# Symfony4.1 Doctrine ManyToMany Reduce No of Queries

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony4

I'm working on a project. Entity are Blog,Category,Tags. Blog and Tags are in **ManyToMany** Relation. My repository query to fetch data by Tags filter is.

**CODE1:**

```
/**
 * @return BlogPost[]
 */
public function getAllActivePostsByTags($value, $order = "DESC", $currentPage = 1, $limit = 10)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        // ->select('p','t')
        ->innerJoin('p.blogTags', 't')
        ->where('t.slug = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $value)
        ->orderBy('p.id', $order)
        ->getQuery();

    $paginator = $this->paginate($query, $currentPage, $limit);

    return $paginator;
}
```

This code works fine. All the tags(No of tags in a post)are displayed correctly. But the **No of DB Query is 14**. Then When I uncomment *select* as this,

**CODE2:**

```
/**
 * @return BlogPost[]
 */
public function getAllActivePostsByTags($value, $order = "DESC", $currentPage = 1, $limit = 10)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p','t')
        ->innerJoin('p.blogTags', 't')
        ->where('t.slug = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $value)
        ->orderBy('p.id', $order)
        ->getQuery();

    $paginator = $this->paginate($query, $currentPage, $limit);

    return $paginator;
}
```

**No of Query is 9.** But The Tags per Post is only one(Not displaying all the tags of a single post).

**To be clear info:**

- It displays entire list of BlogPost.
- But not all Tags of a Post.
- Only one Tag per Post is shown.

**Question:** Is *code1* is correct (No of DB Query = 14) or Do I have to tweak little bit to reduce no of DB Hits. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jannes Botis for refresh. But in my case the code itself is wrong. There need a slight change in it.

BlogTags.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BlogPost", mappedBy="blogTags")
 */
private $blogPosts;
```

BlogPost.php

```
/**
 * @var Collection|BlogTags[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BlogTags", inversedBy="blogPosts", cascade={"refresh"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *  name="fz__blog_n_tag",
 *  joinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *  }
 * )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name": "ASC"})
 */
private $blogTags;
```

This created the join_table. **Allready I have a join_table. Although This code is for reference to someone.**

Controller.php

```
// This is my old Code
$bp = $em->getRepository('App:BlogPost')->getAllActivePostsByTags($slug, "DESC", $page, self::PAGE_LIMIT);
// This is my New Code
$bp = $em->getRepository('App:BlogTags')->getAllActivePostsByTags($slug, "DESC", $page, self::PAGE_LIMIT);
```

Repository.php

```
public function getAllActivePostsByTags($value, $order = "DESC", $currentPage = 1, $limit = 10)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t','p','tx')
            ->innerJoin('t.blogPosts', 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.blogTags', 'tx')
            ->where('p.isActive = :val1')
            ->andWhere('t.slug = :val2')
            ->setParameter('val1', true)
            ->setParameter('val2', $value)
            ->orderBy('p.id', $order)
            ->getQuery();

        $paginator = $this->paginate($query, $currentPage, $limit);

        return $paginator;
    }
```

I not changed my old twig file completely. As it throws error at many places. Because now i'm using tags repo instead of blog. So i modified the twig with

```
{% include 'frontend/page/blog_home.html.twig' with { 'bp':bp|first.blogPosts } %}
```

**Help me on this (twig file):** There is only one tag, that's why |first twig filter
Clarify me with this twig filter. Do I'm doing right. Give me suggestion to improve on it. I tried bp[0] This trows error.

**Finally:** By using old code in controller it returns 14 db hits. Now it returns only 8. Even there are more tags in a post (but old one returns more).

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour in both cases.

**Case 1)** You just select the BlogPost entities. So you tell doctrine to fetch all BlogPosts that have the BlogTag that has slug = value.
The SQL query produced returns only column values from the blog_post table and so **only hydrates the BlogPost entities** returned, it does not hydrate the collection of BlogTags inside each BlogPost.

When you try to access the tags of a BlogPost **a new query** is generated to get and hydrate its collection.

That is the reason you get **more queries** in this case.

**Case 2)** You select also the filtered BlogTag entities, and doctrine **hydrates(puts) only this filtered BlogTag** to each BlogPost `s collection.

When you try to access the BlogTags of a BlogPost, you get the filtered one that meets the condition in the querybuilder.

To force doctrine to "reload" the data from the database, you should **refresh** the blogPost entity:

```
 $em->refresh($blogPost);
```

and also include **refrech** option on [cascade operations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) of the relation definition:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="BlogTag", mappedBy="post", cascade={"refresh"})
```

References:

- [what cascade refresh means in doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897830/what-cascade-refresh-means-in-doctrine-2)
- [refresh objects: different question but same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678838/doctrine2-orm-doesnt-refresh-objects-that-are-altered-outside-of-a-script)